# Possible errors in a paper about RANSAC

Tags: computer-vision, ransac

The problem comes from

[*Raguram, R., Chum, O., Pollefeys, M., Matas, J., & Frahm, J. M. (2013). Usac: a universal framework for random sample consensus. IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis & Machine Intelligence, 35(8), 2022-38.*](http://xueshu.baidu.com/s?wd=paperuri%3A%289959b0a8e62a5c9f29f25f95e6a71744%29&filter=sc_long_sign&tn=SE_xueshusource_2kduw22v&sc_vurl=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fdocument%2F6365642%2F&ie=utf-8&sc_us=12879230457634169498)

In section 2.2.3, it states:[image]

To my understanding,`epsilon` is the fraction of inliers in the dataset,then [image] will be greater than 1, who can help?

Comment: This is not the first paper with an error in it. Did you try contacting the authors?

Comment: Yeah, I have emailed it to the first and second author. But no replies are returned so far.